# Wait for DOM-ready state to init amchart on dynamically added element

Tags: angular, dynamic, amcharts

I’m using dynamic gridster which allow the user to create various type of widgets.

These widgets are created in an ngFor directive, so I just push a new widget to an array and want to init chart, but it seems the element is not in the DOM already.

I know there is a possible reference to ViewChild, but there isn't any maximum supported length. Also, I can easily use setTimeout, but it seems not a very good approach to me. Also, amchart have a ready() function, but in this case, it doesn't help, because it refers to library init and not a chart container.

```js
// Main array of data
let widgets = [
   {type: 'chart', id:'uniqueID'};
];

// Simply generate a new widget
createChart() {
   let chartWidget = {type: 'chart', id: 'uniqueID2'};
   this.widgets.push(chartWidget);
   let amchart = this._amChartsService
                    .makeChart(chartWidget.id, {chartOpt});
};
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let widget of widgets>
   <div [attr.id]="widget.id"></div>
</div>
```

This solution is only to the freshly created HTML element. After I save data and load it again, there is a lifecycle event that handles it for me.

Is there a feature like ngDoCheck to let me know if the ngFor directive actually created the element and it’s available?

Or any amcharts master solutions?

Answer (score 1):

It was pretty easy but I have to change my mind about it.

As I suggest Angular has various life cycle events so I just managed to create a new component and use predefined AfterViewInit like this.

```
<!-- Parent template with gridster -->
<div *ngFor="let widget of widgets>
   <chart [widget]="widget"></chart>
</div>
```

```
// "chart" component
export class Chart implements AfterViewInit {

   @Input() widget:Chart;

   /**
     * After view is inited
     * Now I know that HTML element is in DOM
     */
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.createChart();
    }
}
```

I’m not including all part’s of code but anybody who will struggle with this problem should know how to continue.